# Arrow in Timepicker

Tags: android, timepicker

I have a timepicker showing the choice, but also shows the previous option above, and the next option below. I wish they would show these options are not, and it would show arrows such as in the image attached: http://www.subirimagenes.net/i/140728103732203512.png.

I have searched but have not found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

From android/widget/NumberPicker.java:

> If the current theme is derived from android.R.style#Theme the
>   widget presents the current value as an editable input field with an
>   increment button above and a decrement button below.
>
> If the current theme is derived from android.R.style#Theme_Holo or
>   android.R.style#Theme_Holo_Light the widget presents the current value
>   as an editable input field with a lesser value above and a greater
>   value below.

According to this, before Holo the widget looked exactly how you wanted it. So try adding `android:style="@android:style/Theme.Black"` inside the `<TimePicker />` in your layout xml file.

Comment: Indeed, making these changes the arrows shows timepicker, but the style is pre Holo and that style is not what I want. I want to use the same style as that showed in the picture. What for this case there would be another solution?

Comment: Under Holo, the widget is hardcoded to behave as it does. The only solution in this case would be to copy the whole NumberPicker.java source file and then make changes. This could prove messy.